# What is a good way to translate an English non–restrictive relative clause? e.g. "The birds, which are beautifully-coloured, are eating all the food."

Tags: grammar

> The birds, which are beautifully-coloured, are eating all the food.

This conveys that:

- All the birds being spoken about are beautifully-coloured
- All the birds are eating all the food
- the second piece of information (that the birds are eating all the food) is the more important one.

What's the best way to translate that into Korean whilst preserving the meaning?

If I say 아름다운 빛깔의 새들이 모이를 다 먹는다, I think that could be taken to imply that there are some less beautiful birds which are not eating the food, which is a different meaning.

Comment: See https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/restrictive-and-non-restrictive-modification-in-korean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example sentence ("아름다운 빛깔의 새들이 모이를 다 먹는다") is good enough, given enough context.

If the context is ambiguous, I'd suggest restructuring it: 새들은 빛깔이 아름다운데, 이 새들이 모이를 다 먹고 있습니다.

Comment: I was thinking that ㄴ데 might be appropriate!